# How to use node js with API

Tags: node.js, api, http

i'm woking with a sports API from https://brokersports.ddns.net/
I have a problem with this code in node.js which allows to display the data from an API :

```
request.get("https://brokersports.ddns.net/api/v2/soccer/")
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer m_key")
        .header("Accept", "application/json")
        .end(function (result) {
        console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);
        });
```

this code is not working and i dont know why

I have this error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined
```

some one can help me!!

Answer (score 0):

To use the [`request` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) you have to [install it](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install) and then load it into your module with [`require`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) or [`import`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_node_imports) (depending on if you are writing a CommonJS module (the default) or an ES6 module).

(If you haven't created a project with a `package.json` yet, start [with this tutorial](https://nodesource.com/blog/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-using-npm/)).

But don't use the `request` module: it is deprecated. Switch to something supported such as [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch). All the above will still apply to those modules though.